my api key is being signaled as having a syntax error on a script i'm using to send to a private transaction on optimism network
file:///C:/Users/HP/private-sendtx/sendPrivateTx.mjs:7
const { rVCbipD-Y1F, "private_key is here" }  = process.env;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'
at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:18)
at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:272:14)
at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:30)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:21)
Node.js v20.14.0

Please provide more context, share the script without your keys or the API key

There's a syntax error in you snippet: rVCbipD-Y1F isn't a valid identifier name for javascript. The whole line seems to be wrong. Why are you destructuring process.env into values?
